# Working with $_GET[page_id]

Tags: php, detect

Okay, this might be a basic question.
Here is my code:

```
<?php $pageid = $_GET[page_id]; ?>
```

And then:

```
<a href="" <?php if($pageid == '2' OR $pageid == '9') { echo...
```

So this makes it so that if they are on page ID 2 or 9, then it will echo a message. Now what I want to do is that I want to add index.php as one of those pages. But index.php does not have a page id. So I want `<?php if($pageid == '2' OR $pageid == '9' OR index.php) { echo...`
How the heck do I do that? Just placing the filename wont work obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `index.php` has no `pageid`, then simply put your `if()` to...

`<?php if($pageid == '2' || $pageid == '9' || !isset($_GET['page_id'])) { echo...`

Answer (score 2):

`if($pageid == '2' || $pageid == '9' || __FILE__ == 'index.php')`

Comment: Add basename to the __FILE__. __FILE__ returns the file name and the path to the file

Comment: Could you please define basename? note that I am not very experienced with php

Answer (score 0):

I would start your script with

```
 $pageid = false;
```

Then in your if statement you ca do

```
 <a href="" <?php if($pageid == '2' OR $pageid == '9' OR !$pageid) { echo...
```

That way if you never set pageid (aka index.php) then you are set in your if statement!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $pageid = (isset($_GET[page_id]) ? $_GET[page_id] : 'index'); ?>
```

Then $pageid would contain either the page_id or 'index' if it wasn't supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page_id']) {
    $pageid = 0;
}
```

so you're always working with page ids, even when one isn't supplied.

Comment: Could you please explain this further: "so you're always working with page ids, even when one isn't supplied"

Comment: @Alehandro - What I mean is if the page id isn't set, set it anyway, then whatever you do you're always checking the page id, rather than (a) checking page id or (b) checking whether you're on the index page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if they are on the index by using the base URI.  So do this:

if($pageid == '2' || $pageid == '9' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/')